# Writing array with pywin32 to excel

Tags: arrays, excel, pywin32

I am trying to write an array into Excel.  The code snippet is below.

import win32com.client as win32
import sys
import numpy as np
#--------------
if **name**=="**main**":

```
name="nlve9.xlsm"
excel=win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
sheet=excel.Workbooks(name).Worksheets('NLVE')
#--------------
testress=np.zeros(5000)
for i in range(0,5000):
    testress[i]=float(i)

sheet.Range("AC18:AC5016").value=testress
#excel.ScreenUpdating = False
#for i in range(18,5017):
#    sheet.Range("AC" + str(i)).value=testress[i-18]
#excel.ScreenUpdating = True
sys.exit()
```

```
When this runs, I get a column of zero the length of testress.  When I replace the last line with below it works but it is excruciatingly slow.  THs is part of an optimization problem so this will run hundreds of times. Hence, I need this to be fast.

for i in range(18,5017):
    #    sheet.Range("AC" + str(i)).value=testress[i-18]
```

What am I doing wrong with the first method(sheet.Range("AC18:AC5016").value=testress)?

Comment: What do you mean it's too slow? how many rows do you have?  [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code before opening the file besides being incomplete, is totally irrelevant.

Comment: It is but it gives context.  The code takes 5-6 seconds to run.  If I select the Excel window, the code crashes with the following:

 File "prf2.py", line 425, in <module>or\Projects\Packaging\Marlex - Boyet>
    sheet.Range("AC" + str(i)).value=testress[i-18]
  File "C:\Users\hamm.rw.2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 707, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Property 'Range.value' can not be set.

When I time the method without the loop, it takes <1 second.  But it also gives me a bunch of zeros.

Comment: You could populate the array with some dummy data, as one would not care how you obtain those values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Range.Value` property to set an array, Excel needs a 2D array of row & column values, even if your data is a 1D array.

`[[r1c1,r1c2,...],[r2c1,r2c2,...] ...]`

As an example:

```
import win32com.client as wc

xl = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True

wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
sh = wb.Sheets[1]

sh.Range('A1:A10').Value = [[i] for i in range(10)]
```

yielding:

[image]

EDIT:

From the OP's code, change:

```
testress=np.zeros(5000)
for i in range(0,5000):
    testress[i]=float(i)

sheet.Range("AC18:AC5016").value=testress
```

to:

```
rowCount = 5000
testress = [[i] for i in range(rowCount)]
sheet.Range('AC18:AC'+str(18+rowCount-1)).Value = testress
```

Comment: Thank you!  this still puts me in loop that cycles through every element.  I there a method that would allow me to dump an entire array into a range all at once?

Comment: @RichHamm My code does 'dump the entire array' all at once (I'm not sure what code you are now using). The only loop is the list comprehension on the Python side where the dummy array is created. `sh.Range('A1:A10').Value=` sets all the values of the range in one hit, which is the entire point. Even if I set the range size to 10,000 items, the `Value` call is near instantaneous on my system (timed it roughly at 16ms), which is what I would expect.

Comment: Thanks!  I have to admit I am a bit new to Python and tried to apply this to my code, but I cannot get the syntaxt correct and cannot find documentation to help.

sheet.Range("AC18:AC" + str(rowcount+17)).value=[testress[[i] for i in range(1,rowcount)]]

along with a few variants of this.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @RichHamm Added an edit specific to your code

Comment: It worked!!!  thank you!